# Crystal Report filtering by formula field

Tags: crystal-reports, vb6

Im new in crystal report, Im doing a very simple report with one filter.
I am passing a parameter from VB6 to crystal report "BranchID" and putting it in a formula field: @BranchID. The value is passing correctly.

I need to filter the report according to this value. In the Select expert I added the following formula in the Formula Editor: {ado.Branch Name} = {@BranchID},but all fields are disappearing after I add it.

If I specify a value in the filter ({ado.Branch Name} = "NewYork") it will filter the report normally according to this specific value.

Anyone have an idea what i missed?

Please note Crystal-Report is version: 8.0.1

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

I see you are comparing the ID to String.... `{ado.Branch Name}` is string and {@BranchID} is Integer hence you are getting wrong data

String should be compared strings and number to number

Comment: Correct, my bad, now I created a parameter field and I was able to pass the value using . ParameterFieldName, unfortunetly as soon as the report loads a prompt pop up asking to enter the variable again in the "Enter parameter fields" box, and the report don't show anything.

Comment: Still you cant see the data?